# How to change the marker in a stripplot legend in seaborn

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, seaborn, legend

The legend of a seaborn stripplot only shows the colored circles, however, the marker shapes are not respecting the marker that I set.

Code for reproduction:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

letters = list('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')
place = ['North', 'South', 'East', 'West']

letter_set1 = set("abcdefghijklmn")
letter_set2 = set("opqrstuvwxyz")

data_size = 100

df_dict = {'letter': np.random.choice(letters, data_size), 
           'place': np.random.choice(place, data_size),
           "height": np.random.randint(low=40, high=100, size=data_size),
          "weight": np.random.randint(low=150, high=210, size=data_size),}

df = pd.DataFrame(df_dict)
print(df)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(10, 7))

# We can ignore the violinplot
sns.violinplot(x='place', y="weight", data=df, scale="width", inner="quartile", bw=0.2, linewidth=1,
)
for violin in ax.collections:
    violin.set_alpha(0.1)

set1_df = df[df['letter'].isin(letter_set1)]
set2_df = df[df['letter'].isin(letter_set2)]

sns.stripplot(data=set1_df, x='place', y="weight", hue="letter", palette="Set1", size=10, linewidth=0.05, marker='^', ax=ax
)
sns.stripplot(data=set2_df, x='place', y="weight", hue="letter", palette="Set2", size=10, linewidth=0.05, marker='D', ax=ax
)

# Update the legend oreder
handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
zipped_list = zip(handles, labels)
sorted_zipped_list = sorted(zipped_list, key=lambda x: x[1])
ordered_handles, ordered_labels = [x[0] for x in sorted_zipped_list], [x[1] for x in sorted_zipped_list]

ax.legend(
    handles=ordered_handles,
    labels=ordered_labels,
    title="Letter",
    bbox_to_anchor=(1.02, 1),
    loc="upper left",
    )
plt.tight_layout()

plt.show()
plt.close()
```

Figure output:
[image: output]

**Goal: change the colored circles in the legend to diamonds and triangles.**

The legend handles are all `matplotlib.collections.PathCollection` objects, which do not have obvious way to change. I also found an open issue on GitHub: https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/940 (for reference).

Does anyone have idea on how to manually set the markers in the legend or some other quick ways to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be an [open issue](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/940) in seaborn's github. A workaround could be to create the legend handles manually:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D

letters = list('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')
place = ['North', 'South', 'East', 'West']

letter_set1 = set("abcdefghijklmn")
letter_set2 = set("opqrstuvwxyz")

data_size = 100

df_dict = {'letter': np.random.choice(letters, data_size),
           'place': np.random.choice(place, data_size),
           "height": np.random.randint(low=40, high=100, size=data_size),
           "weight": np.random.randint(low=150, high=210, size=data_size)}

df = pd.DataFrame(df_dict)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(10, 7))

sns.violinplot(x='place', y="weight", data=df, scale="width", inner="quartile", bw=0.2, linewidth=1)
for violin in ax.collections:
    violin.set_alpha(0.1)

set1_df = df[df['letter'].isin(letter_set1)]
set2_df = df[df['letter'].isin(letter_set2)]

marker_set1 = '^'
marker_set2 = 'D'
marker_for_letter = {**{letter: marker_set1 for letter in letter_set1},
                     **{letter: marker_set2 for letter in letter_set2}}
sns.stripplot(data=set1_df, x='place', y="weight", hue="letter",
              palette="Set1", size=10, linewidth=0.05, marker=marker_set1, ax=ax)
sns.stripplot(data=set2_df, x='place', y="weight", hue="letter",
              palette="Set2", size=10, linewidth=0.05, marker=marker_set2, ax=ax)
handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
handles = [Line2D([], [], color=h.get_facecolor(), linestyle='',
                  marker=marker_for_letter[l])
           for h, l in zip(handles, labels)]
labels, handles = zip(*sorted(zip(labels, handles)))

ax.legend(handles, labels, title="Letter", bbox_to_anchor=(1.01, 1.01), loc="upper left")
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: stripplot with custom markers and updated legend]

Comment: Thanks @JohanC! The method to create the legend handle manually helps a lot! I have some more data set to plot. I may need extra work to format everything correctly. Also, I just modified the seaborn code with the hint from the comments in the open issue on GitHub and had a temporary solution. I will post it here below later.

Comment: I updated the code using a dictionary for the markers.

Comment: The code optimization of the `zip(*sorted(zip()))` around handles and labels are also great.

Comment: Oops. It should be `labels, handles = zip(*sorted(zip(labels, handles)))`, to let the sort happen using the default key. I'm changing that line of the code.

Comment: Nice, it's even shorter. : )

Answer (score 0):

Followed by the hint from the [comments](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/940#issuecomment-224369014) in the open issue [#940](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/940) on GitHub, I modified the code accordingly to have a temporary solution.

I modified this file: /<your_python_dir>/lib/python3.8/site-packages/seaborn/categorical.py

Around L1084: add `kws={"marker": "o"}` to the input argument, add `marker=kws['marker'],` to the input argument passed into `ax.scatter()`:

```py
def add_legend_data(self, ax, kws={"marker": "o"}):
"""Add empty scatterplot artists with labels for the legend."""
    if self.hue_names is not None:
        for rgb, label in zip(self.colors, self.hue_names):
            ax.scatter([], [],
                       color=mpl.colors.rgb2hex(rgb),
                       label=label,
                       marker=kws['marker'],
                       s=60)
```

Around L1162, add `kws` to `self.add_legend_data(ax)`:

```py
def plot(self, ax, kws):
    """Make the plot."""
    self.draw_stripplot(ax, kws)
    self.add_legend_data(ax, kws)
    self.annotate_axes(ax)
    if self.orient == "h":
        ax.invert_yaxis()
```

The downside could be, you may have to pass the `marker` argument to the `stripplot()` function every time, otherwise we get a KeyError. Also, this method is not portable. You have to edit this way on all machines.

**Proceed at your own risk.**